# Array of chars from an array of pointer to strings in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have a line input from a user that I stored in an array of chars `input`. I copied the string `input` to another array `words` and used `strtok` with space delimiter to store individual words into an array of pointers to string `astArray[]`. Now the individual words are stored in the memory location pointed by `*astArray` and individual chars of the word pointed by `*token`.

After I modified what needed to be done on the words, I would like to reconstruct the array of char `input` back with the strings stored at `astArray`.  I would like to copy all strings to the array of char `input` with a space between them and a null at the end. How would I do that? I tried `strcpy` but I got the characters with no space in between.

Memory was allocated.

```
* token
token = strtok(words, " ");
loop
strcpy(astArray[i], token);
```

Comment: Can you post what you have done

Comment: You should use code formatting.  This is hard to read.

Comment: If you use strcpy, (strcat?) then you need to put the removed spaces in with " ", like strcat(result," "); to add back the space.  Note if an interval between two words is 2 spaces, you won't recover that precisely, as you will only restore it with a single space.

Comment: don't use `strcpy` use `strlcpy`.  Read the fine [manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strcpy/) and you'll see why `strlcpy` is recommended over `strcpy`.

Comment: OK. How does that solve the problem of adding space between the strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
char *astArray[] = {"The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"};
char input[128];
int wc = 9;

char *out = input;
int i;
for(i=0;i<wc;++i){
    char *p = astArray[i];
    while(*p){
        *out++=*p++;
    }
    if(i<wc-1){
        *out++ = ' ';
    }
}
*out = '\0';
printf("%s\n", input);
```